# Unable to understand "Combinations of pairs of parentheses" algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm

Task: Find the number of regular parenthesized expressions containing N opening and N closing brackets. N is entered from the keyboard.

I found this algorithm for solve and try to understand it.

```
public static void addParen(ArrayList<String> list, int leftRem, int rightRem, char[] str, int count) {
    if (leftRem < 0 || rightRem < leftRem) return; // some state

    if (leftRem == 0 && rightRem == 0) { /* no additional left parentheses */
        String s = String.copyValueOf(str);
        list.add(s);
    } else {
        /* Add left parenthesis if there are parentheses of any kind */
        if (leftRem > 0) {
            str[count] = '(';
            addParen(list, leftRem - 1, rightRem, str, count + 1);
        }

        /* Add a right parenthesis if the expression is true */
        if (rightRem > leftRem) {
            str[count] = ')';
            addParen(list, leftRem, rightRem - 1, str, count + 1);
        }
    }
}
public static ArrayList<String> generateParens(int count) {
    char[] str = new char[count * 2];
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    addParen(list, count, count, str, 0);
    return list;
}
```

But can do it only to first result string: 
((()))

How it continues work? How do we get other pairs of parentheses?
Maybe you can propose other versions for programming this task?

If count = 3, results:

```
((()))
(()())
(())()
()(())
()()()
```

Comment: Please let us know what kind of results the algorithm is expected to produce.

Comment: What is *the task*?

Comment: iuliq I also got lost in the brackets ;(:D

Comment: what if count =4? for now your task is not full

Comment: I should find the number of regular parenthesized expressions containing N opening and N closing brackets. N is entered from the keyboard

Comment: The number of expressions or the list of expressions? (Note that the number gets big very quickly)

Comment: that is more of a logical task and you have a created a mind breaking recursion we can solve the task easier

Comment: no, because for example  ")()("  or "))(("- in-illegal expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your task is to count valid sequences of parentheses, not to output them. So let's think how many variants exist to make a valid sequence of length N (pairs) (denote it S(N)):

```
You can get any valid sequence of length N-1 and add () pair after it  
You can get any valid sequence of length N-2 and add opening parenthesis,
valid sequence of length 1, and closing parenthesis  
...   
You can get any valid sequence of length N-1-M and add opening parenthesis, 
any valid sequence of length M, and closing parenthesis  
...  
You can make opening parenthesis, add any valid sequence of length N-1, 
and closing parenthesis
```

So overall formula:

```
S(N) = Sum[S(N-M-1)*S(M)] for M=0..N-1   (with S(0)=1)
```

Just fill array/list from smaller values to larger.

Example:

```
S(3) = S(2)*S(0)+S(1)*S(1)+S(0)*S(2)=2+1+2=5
```

Note that concise formula does exist, but I think that your instructor expects a solution with some logical conclusion

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, for sure a popular task in programming classes :) And you'd find plenty of solutions on the net in multiple languages like [the one below](http://www.programcreek.com/2014/01/leetcode-generate-parentheses-java/). Actually, this one is quite ugly. Maybe you dig into it and come up with something that caresses a coder's heart to a greater extent :)

```
public static List<String> generateParenthesis(int n) {
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> diff = new ArrayList<>();
    result.add("");
    diff.add(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * n; i++) {
        ArrayList<String> temp1 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> temp2 = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < result.size(); j++) {
            String s = result.get(j);
            int k = diff.get(j);

            if (i < 2 * n - 1) {
                temp1.add(s + "(");
                temp2.add(k + 1);
            }

            if (k > 0 && i < 2 * n - 1 || k == 1 && i == 2 * n - 1) {
                temp1.add(s + ")");
                temp2.add(k - 1);
            }
        }
        result = new ArrayList<>(temp1);
        diff = new ArrayList<>(temp2);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!
Your solution is better...but it also so hard for me! :D